# Are the canonical embeddings into $G*_AH$ quasi-isometric?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Suppose $A,G,H$ are finitely generated groups and $A$ is quasi-isometrically embedded into $G$ and $H$. Does it follow that the natural embeddings of $G$ and $H$ into $G*_AH$ are quasi-isometric?

I can more or less see that this is true if $A$ is finite (in particular, for the free product), or, more generally, if $G$ and $H$ have finite generating sets which are invariant under conjugation by $A$, but I can't quite solve the general case.

This seems like something that should be well-known (one way or the other), but I could not find any information on this in the literature (not even for the case of the free product). If this is true, I would appreciate a reference. (If necessary, I don't mind assuming that $A,G,H$ are hyperbolic, but this seems like something that should be true in general.)

Edit: I am also happy to assume that the embedding of $H$ into $G$ and $H$ is conjugate-separated i.e. that $A\cap A^g$ is finite for $g\in (G\cup H)\setminus A$.

Comment: No, but HNN extension examples are simpler (Baumslag-Solitar groups). Can you see why?

Comment: Yes, I can see that. What if I assume in addition that the embedding of $A$ in $G$ and $H$ is conjugate separated (i.e. $A^g\cap A$ is finite for $g\in (G\cup H)\setminus A$)?

Comment: I think so. I know it is true for hyperbolic $G, H$ but I need to check this in general.

Comment: @tomasz: Your definition of "conjugacy separated" is usually called *almost malnormal* in the geometric-group-theory literature. *Malnormal* means the intersection is trivial instead of finite.

Comment: @tomasz: You mention the case of a free product. This is trivial, since the factors $G$ and $H$ are retracts of the free product $G*H$. It's very easy to check that retracts are quasi-isometrically embedded.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thanks, that is actually enough for me (although a general fact would be more elegant). Do you have a reference? Or does it somehow easily follow from the hyperbolicity of $G*_AH$?

Comment: @HJRW: Thanks for the comments, especially regarding terminology. I pulled this off a not so recent paper, should have figured out it may have a different name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the setting when $G, H$ are hyperbolic groups and $A$ is almost malnormal in $G, H$ (the one you are actually interested in, per your comments), the positive answer is given in

*Kapovich, Ilya*, [**The combination theorem and quasiconvexity**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0218196701000553), Int. J. Algebra Comput. 11, No. 2, 185-216 (2001). [ZBL1025.20028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1025.20028).

On the other hand, if you only assume hyperbolicity of $G, H$ and $G*_AH$, the subgroups $G, H$ need not be quasiconvex in $G*_AH$.

Examples that I know come from topology. Suppose that $S$ is a closed nonorientable hyperbolic surface, $F\to S$ is its orientation double-cover, $C(F\to S)$ the mapping cylinder. The latter is a 3-dimensional manifold with boundary (homeomorphic to $F$). Take two copies $M_1, M_2$ of $C(F\to S)$ and a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism $h: \partial M_1\to \partial M_2$ (this makes sense due to canonical hoomeomorpisms of these boundaries to $F$). Glue $M_1, M_2$ via $h$. The result is a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold $M$. Of course,
$$
\pi_1(M)=\pi_1(M_1)*_{\pi_1(F)} \pi_1(M_2)
$$
and amalgam of two hyperbolic groups over a hyperbolic subgroup of index $2$. At the same time, $M$ admits a 2-fold covering $p: N\to M$ such that $N$ is fibered over the circle, such that the fiber corresponds to a connected component of $p^{-1}(F)$. The fundamental group of the fiber is not quasiconvex in $\pi_1(N)$, hence, $\pi_1(F)$ is not quasiconvex in $\pi_1(M)$.

I am not quite sure what happens if you drop the hyperbolicity assumption but keep (almost) malnormality. I think the answer is still positive.

Answer (score 7):

No. For instance, take two elements $u,v$ of order 2 in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ whose product has infinite order. Take $G=\langle u\rangle\ltimes\mathbf{Z}^2$, $H=\langle v\rangle\ltimes\mathbf{Z}^2$, and $A=\mathbf{Z}^2$. Then $A$ is undistorted in both $G$ and $H$ (it is a subgroup of index 2 in both), but distorted in $G\ast_A H=\langle u,v\rangle\ltimes \mathbf{Z}^2$.

Example:
$$u=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0&-1\end{pmatrix},\;v=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -1&-1\end{pmatrix},\;uv=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
(in this case $\mathbf{Z}^2$ is exponentially distorted in the amalgamated product).